# Developing for Nokia, which is the right technology?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

I want to start development for Nokia devices. I've found the following SDK and I'm lost:

- Qt
- Web
- Java
- Symbian C++
- Adobe Flash
- Open C/C++

When I had a Nokia N70, I used Symbian C++, but now I have a Nokia E7-00 and I don't what SDK must I use.

I want to develop native apps (if it is possible) and sell them at Ovi Store.

Can you clarify my mess?

Answer (score 0):

Ovi store is only available for Symbian phones so Qt / QML is probably the best choice

Comment: Please note that QML applications are not yet deployable in Ovi store (but of course you can write Qt application which doesn't use QML). It'll be probably possible in next few weeks, but it rules out QML if you need to push your app to Ovi store ASAP.

Comment: You have to love Nokia, they have an OS that is used by the majority of their phones which they abandon, they introduce a new app store and a new gui toolkit for the same OS - and the app store doesn't support it!